# padding-top affects border?

Tags: html, css

Adding `padding-top` to an outer container sometimes adds some kind of border. It only happens when I have devtools open. Why does this happen?

My browser is Chrome 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit) in OSX 10.12.6.

```
<style>
.outer {
  background-color:black;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.inner {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}
</style>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Here's a reproduction and a screenshot of the issue.

Note the unexpected **bottom and left border**.

https://jsbin.com/gibesidodi/2/edit?html,css,output

[image: Here's how I see it]

Comment: @dippas: The asker is referring to that grey border around the div. I haven't been able to reproduce it, but something else is at play here. I also originally thought they were asking about the black part.

Comment: @BoltClock Thank you for clarifying it for me. I will edit the question to make myself clear. Have you tried with the devtools open? I only see the borders when I open devtools

Comment: No, I haven't been able to reproduce it regardless of the state of the dev tools. I'm on a PC, so I wonder if this might be yet another Mac-specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Padding is the **area between content and the border**.

So if you add `padding-top`, you move the content `inner` down.

This result in showing `outer` which has `background-color: black`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I am not referring to the top border, rather the unexpected bottom and left border. I have edited the question to clarify myself.

Comment: There is no border showing on my page like yours. I am using Mac and chrome as well.